# How to count a group by with the last 6 months interval?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get the count of 6 months intervals, I have a whole year, and I need to be something like it:

This is not code

```
IdEmpresa = CompanyID
CompanyID = 1 / MONTH(1 TO 6) / YEAR 2019
CompanyID = 1 / MONTH(7 TO 12) / YEAR 2019
CompanyID = 2 / MONTH(1 TO 6) / YEAR 2019 
CompanyID = 2 / MONTH(7 TO 12) / YEAR 2019
CompanyID = 1 / MONTH(1 TO 6) / YEAR 2020
CompanyID = 1 / MONTH(7 TO 12) / YEAR 2020
```

And goes on, always 6 months interval

and bring the count for this interval, as you can see in the img bellow I was trying to do that with:

```
COUNT(C.Id) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(P.DATACADASTRO), MONTH(P.DATACADASTRO), C.IdEmpresa) AS PP
```

and after I'm putting it in a CTE Expression as you can see in the formula bellow
However I can't bring the right results

```
WITH SUP AS 
(
SELECT DISTINCT C.Id AS IdCarro, C.Placa, P.DataCadastro,
MONTH(P.DATACADASTRO) AS MONTH, YEAR(P.DATACADASTRO) AS YEARS, C.IdEmpresa,
CASE 
WHEN P.DataCadastro < DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())
THEN '>1 YEAR'
WHEN P.DataCadastro >= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())
THEN '<=1 YEAR'
ELSE 'NOT FOUND'
END AS WHOLE_YEAR,
        
CONCAT(C.IdEmpresa, YEAR(P.DATACADASTRO), MONTH(P.DATACADASTRO), c.IdEmpresa) AS KEY_SUP_Carro,
COUNT(C.Id) OVER (PARTITION BY  DATEADD(MONTH,3,GETDATE())) AS SEMESTER,
COUNT(C.Id) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(P.DATACADASTRO), MONTH(P.DATACADASTRO)) AS PP
        
FROM Pedido P WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN Carro C WITH (NOLOCK) ON P.IdCarro = C.Id 
AND C.Placa NOT IN ('') AND C.Ativo = 1 AND C.IdEmpresa IN (1, 24, 26, 27)
        
)
SELECT COUNT(IdCarro) AS Contagem, MONTH, YEARS, IdEmpresa, WHOLE_YEAR, KEY_SUP_Carro, 
SEMESTER, PP
       
FROM SUP
GROUP BY MONTH, YEARS, IdEmpresa, WHOLE_YEAR, KEY_SUP_Carro, SEMESTER, PP
        
HAVING WHOLE_YEAR = '<=1 YEAR'
ORDER BY IdEmpresa, YEARS, MONTH DESC
```

[image]

(I have added IdCompany which is not showing in img)

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for your statement, just did as you said :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:
just added a "case" inside my partition by which was counting my IDs.

````
```COUNT(C.Id) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(P.DATACADASTRO),
CASE 
WHEN MONTH(P.DATACADASTRO) >= 1 AND MONTH(P.DATACADASTRO) <= 6
THEN 1
WHEN MONTH(P.DATACADASTRO) >= 7 AND MONTH(P.DATACADASTRO) <= 12
THEN 2
END, C.IdEmpresa) AS PULSE_IdCarro```
````

Then I just added the "PULSE_IdCarro" in my SUP CTE expression, it did the job.